# Freeware tool for modeling a tree structure

Tags: tree, modeling

I am looking for a easy to use freeware tool for modeling a specific tree structure. Does someone has a short hint for me?

thanks a lot!

Comment: i was thinking of marking this for migration to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but the system says "too old to migrate".. now i have to learn why that is..

Comment: .. oh well.  perhaps you could expand on what "specific" tree structure this was about, and make it sound more overflowy?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of [these](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php) graph visualizers, editors, etc...

Comment: the link in this answer is out of date, http://www.graphviz.org/resources/ is the new location.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the Eclipse modeling framework. Everything is available to create your own tree editor easily.
http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/

Here is an article about how to get your own Tree editor in a few steps: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Using%20EMF/using-emf.html

Answer (score 0):

There is TreeTime, please have a look: http://tree-time.info / https://pypi.org/project/TreeTime/. This is a multi-purpose tree editor, you can add numbers, text, there are timers; and it does recursive calculations (adding, subtracting, ratios up and down branches and amoung sibling) and some exports (html, text, csv). It uses multiple trees that are inter-linked.

Also, if you do decide to give it a go, I'd be interested in your opinion. :)